# Validator pattern for angular 2

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, angular2-forms

How do i attach the right **validation string** to this **Validators.pattern array** in the code below.

```
   password: ['', 
    Validators.compose([
    Validators.minLength(8), 
    Validators.maxLength(20),
    Validators.pattern('/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/') 
    ])],
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: The validator pattern is not working.     Validators.pattern('/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/')

Comment: can you remove those / ? it is working for me without the brackets

Comment: thanks so much for you help... can you please show me the code you are using. i.e the validator pattern you are using... as i can  not get mine to work yet.

Comment: Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])'‌​)

Answer (score 1):

You should use first FormControl in order to use Validators, so please follow this code and dont forget you should pass pattern as string, without / :

```
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
password: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(8), 
                Validators.maxLength(20),
                Validators.pattern("(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])")
            ]),
```